# Is the GCC hot attribute redundant in conjunction with always_inline?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

GCC docs describe the function attribute `hot` as placing code in a special subsection of `.text`. My understanding is if the function is always inlined, GCC doesn't have the liberty of placing it wherever it wants in `.text` any more.

The docs also say a function marked as `hot` will be more aggressively optimised, but let's say I'll be compiling with `-O3`.

If I have a function with the GCC attribute `always_inline`, is it ever going to make a difference if I add `hot` to the function's attribute list?

Comment: Unless you *really* know what you are doing, using `always_inline` is usually a mistake. In most cases the compiler is much better at figuring out what it makes sense to inline or not than the human programmer. But, as always with performance related questions; you need to *benchmark* your code to find out what difference it makes in *your* use case.

Comment: GCC's `-O3` is not the same as "all known optimizations".  It is therefore conceivable that even with `-O3` in effect, there are optimizations that will be applied to hot functions that are not applied to others.

Comment: But with that said, you should not be messing with function attributes for the purpose of performance improvement until you know, by measurement, whether you have performance problems in the first place, and if so, where.  At that point, you will then also be able to determine whether applying any of those attributes in fact helps.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for your first comment, I wasn't aware. As for your second comment, I'm not messing with them, just trying to learn about them. Perhaps my second paragraph gave a misleading impression.

Comment: It can make a difference, if you call this function via a function pointer. Or through virtual table.